# Excel - logic for skipping rows in a formula

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, array-formulas

I am trying to do the following via a formula rather than VBA/macro (i do not want a copy/paste special solution as i need more control). is it possible to:

I have a column in which there are some blank rows and some rows with values. let's call that column A. In column b, i only want to copy the cells if the column A has a value. if it doesn't, i want it to skip to the next cell in column A, but stay on on the same cell for column b.

Column A

1

2

[blank]

4

[blank]

6

i want column b output to be (but with no blank rows). this would imply that somehow the formula would need to loop and have some loop skipping logic:

1

2

4

6

Normally i would just set cell B1 = A1 to copy it over, but since i want to skip rows that are blank in column A, i'm not sure what to do besides right a macro. Can i use an array or any other creative solution? Eventually, i would also use this for items with specific values (not just blanks).

thanks!

Comment: If you want to use barry's solution below for a multiple conditions, you can do something like the following (ignores empty cells and cells with value "8"):

=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$10,SMALL(IF((A$1:A$10<>8)*(A$1:A$10<>""),ROW(A$1:A$10)-MIN(ROW(A$1))+1),ROWS(B$1:B1))),"")

___________________________________________________________________
You can't use conditionals in arrays, but you can do the following: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/12/04/logical-operations-in-array-formulas/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generically in cell C2 copied down....

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Range,SMALL(IF(Range=criteria,ROW(Range)-MIN(ROW(Range))+1),ROWS(C$2:C2))),"")`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

so here if your data is in A1:A10 and you want results from B1 down

`=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$10,SMALL(IF(A$1:A$10<>"",ROW(A$1:A$10)-ROW(A$1)+1),ROWS(B$1:B1))),"")`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copied down

when you run out of data you get blanks

Comment: I just tried this, but both formula's have  a syntax error and i can't figure out where. can you please take a look again? thanks!

Comment: i think i fiexed the error. it was missing a ')' in the true portion of the if. but it's giving me the wrong result. but it's close:

Comment: data in rows A1-A7:
1,
2,
3,
blank,
5,
blank,
7


result in cells B1-B7
blank,
1,
1,
3,
5,
blank,
blank

Comment: Thanks. Both versions have a slight error. also, i'm not sure why it's giving two 1's for the first result in column b1. also, looks like this is using a small, but i would like to leave the order the same. any suggestions?

Comment: you are right, pnuts. the generic version is right: this also worked: =IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$10,SMALL(IF(A$1:A$10<>"",ROW(A$1:A$10)-MIN(ROW(A$1))+1),ROWS(B$1:B1))),"")

Comment: yep, the revised version doesn't reorder. i deleted the wrong one from the comments. the right one is left.

Comment: Apologies - there was indeed a typo in the specific version :( I took out the MIN from the generic one but failed to take out the opening parenthesis immediately after - now edited to be correct....

Comment: .....and yes, it doesn't re-order. SMALL function refers to row numbers not the data (so it works on TEXT too). It finds the row number of each match and then gives you the results in order of ROW, thus retaining the order

Comment: it took me a while to understand what was going on but this is quite ingenious sir. Maybe you could breakdown the formula for a more complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

For BLANKS, just copy ColumnA to ColumnB, select ColumnB, Find & Select, Go To Special..., Blanks, right-click one of the selected cells, Delete... with Shift cells up.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to do it without copy/paste as i have a lot of columns and cells. I need something more automated. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: as you can understand, i could list out 5 columns of sample data, but it simpler to abstract it out to one. i also say that i would like to use a formula in my question (with looping type logic and even state that an array is a potential solution). clearly i'm not looking for a simple copy/paste solution that excel already provides. Barry is on the exact right track with the solution. I just haven't used small and getting a little hung up on it. I don't mean to offend you, but your answer didn't address my question which states what i'm after (a formula, with possibly an array).

Comment: Thanks pnuts! I've updated my question above. I can see how it was confusing. thanks again for taking the time and effort to look and answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the ordering of the numbers (such as an array that will be binned or analyzed with a histogram), then simply copy the row and paste values only in another row. Now just sort the row of values. It will place all the empty cells at the bottom of the selection.